# Right syntax for awk usage in combination with other command inside xargs sh –c

Tags: shell, awk, quoting, xargs

How to make this command work:

```
ls * | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}; awk '{print $1}' {} | uniq'
```

It should do the simple thing: print for each file in the folder its name and `uniq` values in the first column

It does not work because the `$` symbol is recognized as an end of the string symbol, and there should be something to do with quotes, I guess.

The error message:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: You don't need all that crazy `ls | xargs sh...` stuff. Why don't you post an example of input files and expected output ?

Comment: I explained  that the line meant to do: print for each file in the folder its name and uniq values in the first column. for file in *;do echo $file ; awk '{print $1}' $file | uniq ;done - will do the same, but there should be a way to do it with xargs, I don't like that I miss it

Comment: You're using single quotes inside single quotes to start with... I'm not sure why you would want to use the error prone `ls | xargs` but good luck anyway.

Answer (score 10):

The second single quote terminates the first single-quoted string `'echo {}; awk '`. Then `{print $1}` is unquoted, and then there is another single-quoted string `' {} | uniq'`. This should be clear in any editor with syntax highlighting; it's also clear if you look at the syntax highlighting in your question.

Here the simplest approach would be to avoid nested quoting altogether. Pass the awk script as an argument to `sh`.

```
xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "$1"; awk "$0"' '{print $1}' {} | uniq'
```

(I also replaced the `{}` inside the script by the corresponding argument to `sh`. Never use `{}` inside a script: it would be parsed as shell syntax, not as a file name, so it would fail catastrophically on any file name containing shell special characters.)

To effectively include a single quote in a single-quoted literal, use `'\''` (formally this ends the single-quoted literal, then adds a single quote which is interpreted literally due to the preceding backflash, then starts another single-quoted literal; but the effect is the same).

```
xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}; awk '\''{print $1}'\'' {} | uniq'
```

Alternatively, use single quotes at one level and double quotes at the other level, but it gets trickier.

(I assume that your nonsensical commands such as `ls *` are just an extremely simplified example.)

Comment: Excellent workaround for the `awk` script quoting issue; I'll remember that one.  Regarding nonsensical commands from first-time posters, I wouldn't make assumptions such as your last sentence.  ;)  Regardless, this is actually the best answer to the exact title question of the Original Poster.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `xargs` at all.

As I read elsewhere on this site (sorry, can't recall just where) from a top user:

> Yes, `xargs` is a cool toy.  No, you don't need to use it.

This:

```
ls * | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo {}; awk '{print $1}' {} | uniq'
```

Can be **fully replaced** with this:

```
for f in *; do echo "$f"; awk '{print $1}' "$f" | uniq; done
```

This gives you a significant **security** improvement over your previous version, to say nothing of readability and actual functionality.  (Of course the first version doesn't work at all due to attempted nesting of single quotes which is impossible[**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282503/right-syntax-for-awk-usage-in-combination-with-other-command-inside-xargs-sh-c/282655?noredirect=1#comment492008_282657).)

Even if you fix the quoting of your version, however, you are laying yourself wide open.  By stuffing the name of an arbitrary filename into a shell command inside of `-c`, you are *effectively* running `eval` on that filename, and so [there are numerous exploits that could be made](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) simply by crafting specific filenames.  For example, `touch ';rm -rf "$HOME" #'` would result in your home directory being removed.

---

For fully guaranteed handling of odd filenames, including filenames that could be interpreted as `awk` option flags, use the following:

```
for f in *; do printf '%s\n' "$f"; awk '{print $1}' < "$f" | uniq; done
```

Comment: nesting of single-quotes is NOT impossible.  It's just difficult to do correctly and ugly & difficult to read afterwards.

Comment: @cas, there is no way to escape a single quote within single quotes.  There is no way to escape *anything* within single quotes.  You have to *break out* of single quotes to include a literal single quote in an argument, which is not the general meaning of "nesting."  Command substitution with `$(...)` has nesting; single quotes simply do not.  The fact that you can *work around* the impossibility of embedding single quotes within single quotes doesn't *really* make that workaround "nesting," IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

1. piping `ls *` into `xargs` is just plain wrong.  It **will** break if any of the filenames contain spaces, newlines, shell globbing characters, or (depending on what you're running with `xargs`) if they begin with a `-`.

   use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` instead.
2. Nested quotes.  As @Gilles mentions in his answer, there are ways of doing this correctly, but it is **very** easy to get lost and confused if you have multiple levels of nested quotes - and even if you succeed, you will probably have code that you can't (easily) read or understand tomorrow, let alone in six months.

It is **much** easier to just write a script that does what you want and run it with xargs.

If the script works standalone with multiple filename args then it will work with `xargs` - and without having to use `-I {}` (which implies `-L 1`.  FreeBSD's version of `xargs` also has a `-J` option which avoids that problem).

For example, `myscript.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh

for f in "$@" ; do
    echo "$f"
    awk '{ print $1 }' -- "$f" | uniq
done
```

(most versions of `awk` that I tried understand `--` to mean stop processing option args.  `original-awk`, which is the same as freebsd's `awk` doesn't.  If your `awk` doesn't, just remove it from the `awk` command line)

and run it as:

```
./myscript.sh *
```

Note that `*` will match subdirectories as well as files.

or like so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0r /path/to/myscript.sh
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec /path/to/myscript.sh {} +
```

These two will process only regular files in the current directory.

If the input files aren't pre-sorted, use `sort -u` instead of `uniq`.

Comment: +1, but he doesn't really need to use `xargs` at all.  He can just perform the `for` loop directly on the glob expansion (which is [what I suggest doing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282657/135943)).

Comment: true.  using `xargs` is only necessary if the list of files to be processed is generated by some other process (`find`, for example). updating.  also used `--` in case filename args start with `-`.

Comment: @Wildcard - obviously the `for` loop is the better option but not sure why anyone would suggest it - OP already knows about the `for` loop - see the comments on the question... This is a XY question where OP knows about X but just wants to do it with Y.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `echo` and `awk` are just stand-ins for some more difficult task....and this provides a useful example of how to avoid over-complicating things when using `xargs` or `find`.  You can use ridiculous quoting shenanigans if you really want to, but it's simpler to just write a trivial throwaway script.  I've made the same point when people get into quoting difficulties with `ssh` - just write a script, `scp` it, and then run it.